# How to connect to Oracle Database (11g) using EZ-Connect in Visual Studio (With SID and not service name)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to my Oracle DB using ODP.NET Managed Driver.

I have the following information available to me:

Username

Password

Host Name

Port number

SID

I would like to be able to connect using the EZ Connect connection type.  I would think that would make my life easier for when I deploy to different servers.

How can I make this connection?  I get an error when I substitute the SID for the service name.

I can make this connection using the TNS connection type, however I'm not sure how easy that will be to utilize when deploying to qa/prod servers.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What is the SID and what is the service_name. Are they different?

Comment: ORA-12514 TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle.  When I connect with Oracle SQL Developer all I have is the SID and not the service name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According this document [Configuring Naming Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm) EZCONNECT uses the `service_name`. `SID` seems to be impossible.

Unless you have a clustered environment or fail-over configuration they should be equal anyway. However, `service_name` often contains a domain whereas SID does not.

Try the SID with domain name (default = `.world`)

Comment: So you are saying try SID.world?

Comment: That did not work.  I was able to track down the db admin and they do not have the service name defined.